# Branching strategy for version control in tfs

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

New to branching concepts here.

We have a solution under TFS 2013 with no branches. Some of the files in the Solution (Used to marshal methods of a third party module) could be incompatible with previous versions and we have to update the usages in our solution based on the newly provided ones. These files tend to change once in few major releases (They do not get changed in every release).

we'd like to be able to access our previous releases and apply hot fixes as necessary.

Is creating a branch for each major release (along with labeling them) enough to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why not.

Creating a branch / label at the point of a release gives you somewhere to go "back to" and create a hotfix.

The ALM Rangers have a series of blog post articles for this stuff, [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalmrangers/archive/2015/09/18/version-control-walkthrough-part-5-servicing-amp-release-isolation.aspx) is the most appropriate to what you are asking about. I won't try and re-post the content here because it is too long and has lots of pretty pictures.